# Error when deploying Node.js server on Render

Tags: node.js, typescript, deployment, render

I am trying to deploy a server written in TypeScript with Node.js to [Render](https://render.com/), but I encountered an error. Below is the directory structure and some information about how I deploy. Please provide me with your opinions. Thank you!

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only server.ts",
"start": "node build/server.js",
"build": "tsc"
},
```

**This is my folder structure:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sKcf.png

**Render Build Command:** npm install

**Render Start Command:** npm start

**This is my error (Render log):**

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/build/server.js'
   at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
   at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
}
```